Beamer - Undefined control sequence \end{frame}
I am having trouble working with this code :
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  breakatwhitespace=false,        
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},   
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                  
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
  language=Prolog,                
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray},
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=2,                    
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},   
  tabsize=2,                      
  title=\lstname,                  
  morekeywords={not,\},\{,preconditions,effects },            
  deletekeywords={time}            
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page
\title[Des stratégies pour performer au Blokus en C] %optional
{Des stratégies pour performer au Blokus en C}


\author[Zazie] % (optional)
{Zazie}




%End of title page configuration block
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}


%---------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code is for the table of contents after
%the title page
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------


\section{Présentation}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%Changing visivility of the text
\begin{frame}{Présentation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    Nombre de joueur : 2\newline
    Plateau de taille : $14\times14$ \newline
    Nombre de pièces : 21\newline
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
    \begin{center}
     \includegraphics[scale=0.3, center]{pièces_blokus.png}
     \caption{\scriptsize{Issu du document de Chin Hung Chao, Blokus Game Solver}}
     \end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Contexte
        \item Problèmatiques
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Comment implémenter de façon optimale le jeu ?
            \item Comment implémenter les différentes stratégies ?
            \item Sont-elles envisageables ?
        \end{itemize}
        \item Objectifs
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Implémenter le jeu
            \item Implémenter des stratégies
            \item Comparer celles-ci
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

When I compile, it displays the error :
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.110 \end{frame}
                 
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

And
\labelenumi ->{
               \labelenumi }
l.128 \end{frame}
                 
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Before to return in Overleaf, my code compiled correctly but not now, there doesn't have pdf view.
Thank you for your help !

your example is too long. Comment parts until you get a short example.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I've flagged this because your name and details remain in the edit history of both your question and the answer. If their being public is a real problem for you, you should probably also reach out to SE and I would also delete this question temporarily if the site will let you. (But you should know that some of us can view deleted posts, so it is only a bit less public.)

There are a couple of errors in your code:

Don't use the enumitem package with beamer

you must not use \caption outside of an environment like figure

the colour mygray etc. is not defined

don't use special characters like ê in your listing


\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\colorlet{mygray}{gray}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  breakatwhitespace=false,        
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},   
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                  
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
  language=Prolog,                
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray},
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=2,                    
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},   
  tabsize=2,                      
  title=\lstname,                  
  morekeywords={not,\},\{,preconditions,effects },            
  deletekeywords={time}            
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page
\title[Des stratégies pour performer au Blokus en C] %optional
{Des stratégies pour performer au Blokus en C}


\author[Zazie] % (optional)
{Zazie}


\date[2023-2024] % (optional)
{2023-2024}


%End of title page configuration block
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}


%---------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code is for the table of contents after
%the title page
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------


\section{Présentation}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%Changing visivility of the text
\begin{frame}{Présentation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    Nombre de joueur : 2\newline
    Plateau de taille : $14\times14$ \newline
    Nombre de pièces : 21\newline
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
    \begin{figure}
     \includegraphics[scale=0.3, center]{example-image-duck}
     \caption{\scriptsize Issu du document de Chin Hung Chao, Blokus Game Solver}
     \end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Contexte
        \item Problèmatiques
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Comment implémenter de façon optimale le jeu ?
            \item Comment implémenter les différentes stratégies ?
            \item Sont-elles envisageables ?
        \end{itemize}
        \item Objectifs
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Implémenter le jeu
            \item Implémenter des stratégies
            \item Comparer celles-ci
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Stratégies}

\begin{frame}{Stratégies}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Aléatoire
        \item Algorithme glouton
        \item Algorithme glouton avancé
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\section{Implémentation du jeu}
\subsection{Début difficile}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstI{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}, caption=Implémentation naïve]
typedef struct carre carre;
typedef struct piece piece;

struct carre {
    int x;
    int y;
    carre* suiv;
};

struct piece{
    int id;
    int taille;
    int nb_coins;
    float densite;
    int x;
    int y;
    carre* points;
    carre* coins;
    int* points_x;
    int* points_y;
    int* coins_x;
    int* coins_y;
    piece* suiv;
    couple_int* refpt;
};
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Début difficile}
\lstI
\end{frame}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstII{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}, caption=Implémentation avec trop de zéro]
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int shape[PIECE_SIZE][PIECE_SIZE];
    int size;
    float density;
} piece;

typedef struct {
    int cells[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
}board;

piece pieces1[MAX_PIECES] = {
// ID 0
{
        .id = 0,
        .shape = {
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        },
        .size = 1,
        .density = 1.0 // 1 block / (1 width * 1 height)
    },
    // ID 1
    {
        .id = 1,
        .shape = {
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        },
        .size = 2,
        .density = 1.0 // 2 blocks / (2 width * 1 height)
    },
// [...]
}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\subsection{Déjà un peu mieux}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Déjà un peu mieux}
\lstII
\end{frame}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstR{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}, caption=Implémentation productive]
static int Pieces[21][4][5][5] = {
    // piece 0
    {
        {
            {1}
        },
    },
    // piece 1
    {
        {
            {1},
            {1}
        },
        {
            {1, 1},
        },
    },
    // piece 2
    {
        {
            {1},
            {1},
            {1}
        },
        {
            {1, 1, 1},
        },
    },
    // piece 3
    {
        {
            {1, 0},
            {1, 1}
        },
        {
            {1, 1},
            {1, 0}
        },
        {
            {1, 1},
            {0, 1}
        },
        {
            {0, 1},
            {1, 1}
        },
    },
// [...]
}
// nombre de rotation maximum ; hauteur ; largeur ; taille
static int Piece_Info[21][4] = {
    {1, 1, 1, 1},  // 0
    {2, 2, 1, 2},  // 1
    {2, 3, 1, 3},  // 2
    {4, 2, 2, 3},  // 3
// [...]
}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\subsection{La révélation}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{La révélation}
\lstR
\end{frame}

\section{Implémentation des stratégies}
\subsection{Aléatoire}
\defverbatim[colored]\lstAlea{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}, caption=Stratégie aléatoire]
bool aleatoireStrat (joueur* player){
    if (player->nbCoins != 0){
        int p = player->nbCoins;
        int* dispoPiece = malloc(p*sizeof(int));
        memset(dispoPiece, 0, p*sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0 ; i < p ; i++){
            dispoPiece[i] = player->tab[i];
        }
        while (dispoPiece != NULL){
            int aleat = rand()%p;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < Piece_Info[dispoPiece[aleat]][0] ; i++){
                point* movePiece = possibleMovePiece(player, Pieces[dispoPiece[aleat]][i]);
                if (movePiece != NULL){
                    majPlateauJoueurScore(player, Pieces[dispoPiece[aleat]][i], movePiece[0].x, movePiece[0].y, aleat);
                    free(dispoPiece);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            for (int i = aleat ; i < p-1 ; i++){
                dispoPiece[i] = dispoPiece[i+1];
            }
            dispoPiece = realloc(dispoPiece, p-1);
            p --;
        }
        free(dispoPiece);
        return false;
    }
    else if (player->count == 21){
        int x;
        int y;
        if (player->couleur == 1){
            x = 0;
            y = BOARD_SIZE-1;
        }
        else {
            x = BOARD_SIZE-1;
            y = 0;
        }
        int alea = rand()%21;
        bool findPiece = false;
        while (findPiece == false){
            for (int i = 0 ; i < Piece_Info[alea][0] ; i++){
                if (verifPosition(x, y, player, Pieces[alea][i])){
                    majPlateauJoueurScore(player, Pieces[alea][i], x, y, alea);
                    findPiece= true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; // pas possible mais je le mets tout de meme
    }
    else {
        return false; // ca peut etre une fin de jeu
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Aléatoire}
\lstAlea
\end{frame}

\subsection{Algorithmes gloutons}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstG{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}, caption=Algorithme glouton simple]
bool gloutonStrat (joueur* player){
    qsort(player->tab, player->count, sizeof(int), compareSimple);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < player->count ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < Piece_Info[i][0] ; j++){
            if (possibleMovePiece(player, Pieces[i][j]) != NULL){
                point* possible = possibleMovePiece(player, Pieces[i][j]);
                majPlateauJoueurScore(player, Pieces[i][j], possible[0].x, possible[0].y, i);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstGA{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}, caption=Algorithme glouton avancé]
bool gloutonAvance (joueur* player){
    qsort(player->tab, player->count, sizeof(int), compareSimple);
    qsort(player->tab, player->count, sizeof(int), compareAvance);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < player->count ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < Piece_Info[i][0] ; j++){
            if (possibleMovePiece(player, Pieces[i][j]) != NULL){
                point* possible = possibleMovePiece(player, Pieces[i][j]);
                majPlateauJoueurScore(player, Pieces[i][j], possible[0].x, possible[0].y, i);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Algorithme glouton simple}
\lstG
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Algorithme glouton avancé}
\lstGA
\end{frame}

\section{Résultats}

\begin{frame}{Résultats}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Aléatoire / Aléatoire : Complètement aléatoire, sans aucun avantage
    \item Glouton simple / Glouton simple :
    \item Glouton avancé / Glouton avancé :
    \item Aléatoire / Glouton simple :
    \item Glouton simple / Aléatoire : Victoire à chaque fois éclatante du premier joueur
    \item Glouton avancé / Glouton simple :
    \item Glouton simple / Glouton avancé :
    \item Glouton avancé / Aléatoire :
    \item Aléatoire / Glouton avancé :
\end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion / Au-delà}
\begin{frame}{Conclusion / Au-delà}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Uniquement des stratégies d'un jeu personnel
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Défense (Exemple : s'éloigner de l'adversaire ou créer des défenses par l'attaque)
            \item Attaque (Exemple : réduire le nombre de coins de l'adversaire)
            \item Contre-attaque
        \end{itemize}
        \item Envisager de comparer les stratégies avec une intelligence artificielle
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Annexe A : pieces.h}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstA{
\lstinputlisting[language=C,caption=pieces.h]{test.C}
}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Annexe A : pieces.h}
\lstA
\end{frame}

\section{Annexe B : joueur.h}
\defverbatim[colored]\lstB{
\lstinputlisting[language=C,caption=joueur.h]{test.C}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Annexe B : joueur.h}
\lstB
\end{frame}

\section{Annexe C : blokus.c}
\defverbatim[colored]\lstC{
\lstinputlisting[language=C,caption=blokus.c]{test.C}
}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Annexe C : blokus.c}
\lstC
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Thanks for your reply, I'm going to need your help again...
My code still won't compile

@ZazieLin I added some more errors to the list

thank you for all !!

@ZazieLin You're welcome!
